# Short Story about Candidates for president. They are connected to a "God Game" - electric shocks for interventionism

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, politics

I think this is from the '50s or 60's.
Two presidential candidates are hooked to a "God Game", which gives (potentially lethal) shocks to a candidate every time they intervene. The protagonist has prophet who has a Biblical Job level bad time, as his God doesn't do anything. In the end, as the prophet lies tortured and dying, he prays one last time for revenge against a rival religions high priest. The prophet points his finger and goes bang,the High Priest dies spectacularly, and the prophet dies happy.

Answer (score 10):

This sounds almost like ["The Short Ones" by Raymond E. Banks](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?40946), told from the point of view of the artificial life forms, the "Short Ones", that tech designers on Earth created.

The story's main drama and viewpoint is "Us" - human people on Earth, with a technology only slightly in our future. (That is, no aliens, space or time travel or other worlds or even a far-off future; it is all in one city on Earth, and a prosaic part of it: politics.) Highly placed government auditors test political candidates by requiring them to control and govern the enclosed colony of two-inch-tall artificial "people" with the most benefit and least harm.

If the controller (political candidate being tested) kills too many creatures, the current no longer used on them goes through the controller’s helmet, incapacitating him.

> In the vast, gloomy auditorium the scurryings and scuttlings of the Short Ones rose to a climax beneath the opaque, milky glass that covered the colony. Several spectators rose in their seats. At the control panel, Charles Melton also rose. The political career of Charles Melton was over: he had failed the Life Hall test.

But there is a dialogue. The story shows events both from the political candidate Controller's, and the artificial Short Ones "Spokesman". So this may be a match for your description about "prophets".
The two "species" interact with normal speech, however the Controller is viewed as a god by the Short Ones, and their Spokesman is exactly that: the designated god-communicator.

And of course the gods change with every political candidate testing. And of course factions arise between believers in the different gods.

> Valsek stumbled over another god-wire before he could answer. Another exposed god-wire!
> He bent to examine the god-wire. The shock to his hands told him there was a feeble current running in it which made his magnetic backbone tingle. Vexing, oh vexing, to know that current ran through the wire and through you, but not to know whether it was the current of the old god, Melton, or  the new god, Hiller!

I would not have thought to match this story to this question, if your description of the ending had not been such a perfect match for the story ending, from the artificial "Short Ones" "Spokesmans" point of view:

"In the end, as the prophet lies tortured and dying, he prays one last time for revenge against a rival religions high priest."

> ....Telfus [the Short Ones' Spokesman] caught hold of himself. "Well", he said, if I could only see King Giron die . . . "

"The prophet points his finger and goes bang,the High Priest dies spectacularly, and the prophet dies happy."

Almost exactly. Ralph is the political candidate tested as Controller. He can kill any Short One A.I., but if he causes too many deaths, the backcurrent will give him permanent brain damage. So whom to kill? Which leader of which riot or faction, to help keep the most peace, prosperity and safety? How to balance a self-governing populace when it has discord or war?

The Short Ones Spokesman Telfus has been fatally wounded by the opposition's King Giron, and asks Ralph (who is an unseen but speaking god to Telfus) for the one last favor: to kill King Giron. Telfus has no power to do it himself. When Ralph agrees, Telfus makes the theatrical appearance of godlike power.

> But Telfus struggled to a sitting position and cried out in a voice that was strangely powerful as if amplified by the voice of a god."I've been permitted one small miracle," he said. .... There was an electric silence. Telfus pointed his empty hand at King Giron with the forefinger extended, like a gun. He dropped his thumb. "Bang," he said. At that moment Ralph gave vent to his pent-up stream of emotions in one lightning-quick flip of the dial of destruction... a microsecond jab. But King Giron's head split open and his insides rushed out like a fat, ripe pea that had been opened and shucked like a celestial thumb. .... "Not bad," said Telfus. "Thanks." He died.

Then the main story viewpoint focuses back on Ralph, his grueling test outcome, his political career and personal drama. That was why I wrote that although it told parts of the story from both human and A.I. viewpoint, the story as a whole started and ended with the humans.

Comment: Yes, this has to be it. I have the story (in The Best from Fantasy and Science Fiction 05 edited by Anthony Boucher) but I hadn't made the connection. Having reread the story it fits the description very well.

Comment: John Rennie: Hey there! You can use the check to accept it, ya know! Oh wait, no; I guess Renovator 99 is the only one who can do that, heh.